# Curl/Laravel fails when loading resource but not when loaded from browser

Tags: php, laravel, apache2

We have a route that pulls JSON data from same server that is hosting the front-end but on a different sub domain. The call always fails with a connection refused error. However, pulling the data by calling the resource route directly works without issue.

Here is the failing code.

```
$client = new Client();
    $response = $client->get("http://api.xxxxx.xx./invoice/".$accountNumber."/".$invoiceNumber."/".$date);
    $invoicecontent = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
```

The above always fails with this error:

ConnectException in CurlFactory.php line 186:
cURL error 7: Failed to connect to api.xxx.xx port 80: Connection refused (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

However, opening the failing page in the browser works perfectly.

Server enviroment: 
Windows 10 
XAMPP 
PHP 7

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it local/dev url? If yes, the curl can't resolve the IP so it cannot connect.

Comment: No, it's a live url. The URL the  it fails to load returns the JSON data if opened in a browser on same machine.